# Extracting a substring from a variable in makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

Basically, I have to match all targets of the form : "tests/mytests-runthis"

I have a rule that does this:

```
life-tests/%:
    ./(?????) < $@.in > runthis.tmp
    -diff runthis.tmp $@.out
```

i need everything after the dash to go in the area "(?????)", so it would run
./runthis < mytests-runthis > runthis.tmp

How can I extract everything after the dash from what i would get from $@?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `patsubst`:

```sh
$ cat Makefile
life-tests/%:
        @./$(patsubst life-tests/%,%,$@).sh

$ cat hello.sh
#! /bin/bash
echo world

$ make life-tests/hello
world
```

Answer (score 0):

The [automatic variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) `$*` expands to the string that matched the pattern (`%`):

```
life-tests/%:
        ./$* < $@.in > runthis.tmp
        -diff runthis.tmp $@.out
```